# How to insert record from an access form to another access table

Tags: forms, ms-access, insert, vba, ms-access-2010

I have 2 access file, their names are A and B.

I've designed a form in access A for receiving data from users, and I want to insert or save data to another table in access B.

I know how insert record to access A tables, but I need to insert to another access file in another place.

Also I'm using this code for insert record to table:

```
 Dim SER As Recordset
 Set SER = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Tbl_A")
 With SER
.AddNew
.Fields("Roz") = Me.Combo_Roz.Value
.Fields("Tarikh") = Me.Text_Tarikh.Value
.Fields("User") = Me.Text_User.Value
.Fields("Saat_Harekat") = Me.Text_Start.Value
.Fields("Saat_Residan") = Me.Text_End.Value
.Fields("Saat_Bargasht") = Me.Text_Bargasht.Value
.Fields("Moshkel") = Me.Text_Moshkel.Value
.Fields("Tozihat") = Me.Text_Reason.Value
.Update
```

Comment: Hi, I posted 2 optional answers, depending on Databes Connection you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this answer for a more easily disposed connection to this table.**
Create a [Linked table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-or-link-to-data-in-another-Access-database-095AB408-89C7-45B3-AAC2-58036E45FCF6?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) to table B in *AccessB*, and insert data to it as if it was a table in you databas:

```
Dim SER As Recordset
'Create the liked table by VBA code:
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "Microsoft Access", "C:\Path\accessB.accdb", acTable, "Tbl_B", "Tbl_B"
'Open a recordset based on linked table, and insert the data:
Set SER = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Tbl_B")
With SER
    .AddNew
    .Fields("Roz") = Me.Combo_Roz.Value
    .Fields("Tarikh") = Me.Text_Tarikh.Value
    .Fields("User") = Me.Text_User.Value
    .Fields("Saat_Harekat") = Me.Text_Start.Value
    .Fields("Saat_Residan") = Me.Text_End.Value
    .Fields("Saat_Bargasht") = Me.Text_Bargasht.Value
    .Fields("Moshkel") = Me.Text_Moshkel.Value
    .Fields("Tozihat") = Me.Text_Reason.Value
    .Update
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this answer if you want a permanent connection to this table.**
Have a Database Object open a connection to *AccessB*, and create the Recordset based on Tbl_B of this Data Base:

```
Dim SER As Recordset
Dim Dbs as DAO.Database
'Open a recordset to AccessB, and insert the data:
Set Dbs = OpenDatabase("C:\Path\accessB.accdb")
Set SER = Dbs.OpenRecordset("Tbl_B")
With SER
    .AddNew
    .Fields("Roz") = Me.Combo_Roz.Value
    .Fields("Tarikh") = Me.Text_Tarikh.Value
    .Fields("User") = Me.Text_User.Value
    .Fields("Saat_Harekat") = Me.Text_Start.Value
    .Fields("Saat_Residan") = Me.Text_End.Value
    .Fields("Saat_Bargasht") = Me.Text_Bargasht.Value
    .Fields("Moshkel") = Me.Text_Moshkel.Value
    .Fields("Tozihat") = Me.Text_Reason.Value
    .Update
End With
```